# UNIX AWK script - memory exhausted

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have an Input CSV file which looks like this:

```
123456,ABC,A,,,
123457,DEF,A,H,,
1234568,GHI,,H,,
111111,AAA,A,,,
12345699,XYZ,A,H,,
```

Now, I have an AWK script containing below lines with multiple IF conditions:

```
BEGIN { FS=","}
{ 
variable=$1.","$2;
if(variable ~ /^123456.+,ABC/) print "P," $0; else
if(variable ~ /^123457.+,DEF/) print "P," $0; else
if(variable ~ /^123458.+,GHI/) print "R," $0; else
if(variable ~ /^1234599.+,XYZ/) print "P," $0; else print "U" ","  $0;} 
END { }
```

After running this AWK script on my input file, I get the below output:

```
P,123456,ABC,A,,,
P,123457,DEF,A,H,,
R,1234568,GHI,,H,,
U,111111,AAA,A,,,
P,12345699,XYZ,A,H,,
```

Everything was running fine till now, but when I had to add more IF conditions to this AWK script (around 3500) it throws a 'memory exhausted' error:

```
awk: script.awk:1259: if(variable ~ /^123311.+,AB23/) print "P," $0; else
awk: script.awk:1259:                                              ^ memory exhausted
```

Now the interesting part:  First, the memory exhausted error comes always at line  1259 and second, when I remove the number of IF conditions after line 1259 (inclusive 1259) then the script runs smoothly again. Is there any limit on the number of IF conditions inside a AWK/GAWK script?

The AWK version which I am using is :

```
GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.3, GNU MP 6.1.0)
```

Comment: Why are you doing `variable=$1.","$2;` ?

Comment: *Is there any limit of using number of IF conditions inside AWK/GAWK script?* ...since yu get a memory exhausted exception, it sound like there is such a limitation. 3500 IFs in a awkscript is... ridiculously much. This really sounds like you should do a generic method, not some crazy AWK-File with thousands of lines.

Comment: first of all I doubt these many conditions could be there in BEGIN section, ok let's consider they are there. Then you should use THUMB rule for any programming which is first create plan which is called data structure then polish it and then before executing also you need to do some fine tuning then after execution we have to see whichever bugs we could fix(sorry for long lecture) but this is TRUE only. Let us know few more details which you could share since I see error is coming on 1259, so people have to see if statements before could cause that also.

Comment: @anubhava: Good Question. It is because there is no direct one-to-one match with column one in my input file. Any IF condition will be fulfilled if the value present in column one in input file starts with that number. I hope you are able to understand what I have mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: @Gewure and RavinderSingh13

I was hoping for some real answers, but thanks for your criticism I will note it down for any future developments.

Comment: @anubhava: Yes you are right, but I want both things to be matched using the script. Complete number or the number starting with 123456. That's why variable is mentioned in the AWK script.

Comment: BTW, this is a job you could probably do much more efficiently with a language that gave you the ability to slice into a sorted sequence. Clojure's `subseq` operation, for instance, is *perfect* for testing whether a sequence starts with any prefix in a large collection in amortized constant time (making the overall operation O(n) for the number of items to be tested), whereas the approach you're taking here is O(n*m) (multiplying the number of items to test by the number of tests).

Comment: @user3676305, Ravinder's suggestion seems like something practicable to me -- it's suggesting the general approach that James Brown is taking, of treating your conditions as data rather than code. While it's surely not fleshed out enough to be an answer (if it were, it would belong below, as an answer, rather than as a comment), writing it off as useless criticism seems a bit harsh.

Comment: FWIW the data driven approach WOULD be good except that the OP has that pesky `.+` in the regexp (so 1234567 is in the same bucket as 123456) and you can't truncate to N significant digits to get a key value because different $1s are of different lengths. It's also not clear if the $2 should be fully or partially matched (does `123456,ABCD` match `123456,ABC`?).

Comment: @EdMorton, it looks like they just have prefix,suffix pairs. That's amenable to a data-driven approach -- note what I suggested before, re: Clojure's `subseq`, letting you find a key closest to the given value, so you can evaluate the keys in your map closest to `1234567`. If awk doesn't have any equivalent facility, maybe it's the wrong language for the job.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy no, there's no equivalent for `subseq` in awk. I wonder how Clojure decides what "closest" means.... Ah, I just read the doc and subseq selects from a previously sorted list so that would be implementable fairly easily for this case. Can't help feeling there's a simpler way though but can't tell what it'd be from the posted sample...

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if there is an `if` limit in GNU awk but don't put so many `if`s in your code, instead solve it with content, a bit like this (it's just a quick draft):

```
$ cat rules   # put your logic here
P,123456,ABC
P,123457,DEF
R,1234568,GHI
```

The code:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }                       
NR==FNR {                                  # read in the rules file
    a[$2","$3]=$1                          # and hash it
    next
}
{                                          # read the input file
    print ($1","$2 in a?a[$1","$2]:"U"),$0 # read code from a hash and it or U if not found
}' rules input                             # mind the order
P,123456,ABC,A,,,
P,123457,DEF,A,H,,
R,1234568,GHI,,H,,
U,111111,AAA,A,,,
U,12345699,XYZ,A,H,,
```

**Edit**:

If you use GNU awk, store only the beginnings of the `$1` and `$2` to a 2D array, you can achieve something like that:

```
$ cat rules   # put your logic here, notice 1st and 3rd
P,123456,ABC
P,123457,DEF
R,123456,GHI
```

The code:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    a[$2][$3]=$1
    next
}
{
    p=substr($1,1,6)
    print (p in a && $2 in a[p] ? a[p][$2] : "U"),$0
}' rules input
P,123456,ABC,A,,,    # matches 1st record in rules file
P,123457,DEF,A,H,,   # 2nd
R,1234568,GHI,,H,,   # 3 rd
U,111111,AAA,A,,,    # no match
U,12345699,XYZ,A,H,, # 123456 would match but XYZ wont
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, looks promising to me. But then it was my fault to give incomplete information in my question.

What my present script does is it checks the first column from the input file and if any line is found which is beginning with "123456" it fulfills the IF condition. For example:

`123456,ABC,A,,,
1234561,ABC,A,,,
1234562,ABC,A,,,
1234563,ABC,A,,,
1234564,ABC,A,,,`
 
All above lines present in the INPUT file fulfills the below IF condition:

`if(variable ~ /^123456.+,ABC/) print "P," $0; else`

I hope I am able to explain here with my example.

Comment: It would really helpful if you can modify your answer according to what I have mentioned above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Updated with another draft.

Comment: Most likely the error is due to the pattern of the if statement. You have already found that without it being there, then it works. I have the feeling that the "greedy" pattern breaks awk.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt if there's a limit on how many stand-alone `if`s there are in your code but **maybe** there's a limit on `if-else`s since that's essentially just one long statement.

Try this to see if you still have a problem or not:

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS=","}
{ variable = $1 "." FS $2 }
variable ~ /^123456.+,ABC/  { print "P", $0; next }
variable ~ /^123457.+,DEF/  { print "P", $0; next }
variable ~ /^123458.+,GHI/  { print "R", $0; next }
variable ~ /^1234599.+,XYZ/ { print "P", $0; next }
{ print "U",  $0 }
```

I also cleaned up a few other things that should have no impact on your problem.

If you can't do the above due to needing to do something else later in your script then:

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS=","}
{ variable = $1 "." FS $2; f=0 }
!f && variable ~ /^123456.+,ABC/  { print "P", $0; f=1 }
!f && variable ~ /^123457.+,DEF/  { print "P", $0; f=1 }
!f && variable ~ /^123458.+,GHI/  { print "R", $0; f=1 }
!f && variable ~ /^1234599.+,XYZ/ { print "P", $0; f=1 }
!f { print "U",  $0 }
```

would be another way to get ride of the `else`s.

Note that I'm not suggesting any of this is a reasonable approach to whatever it is you're trying to do but I don't know enough about what you're really trying to do to suggest another approach so the above is just focused on helping you syntactically get around the error message you're getting.

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
awk -F',' '{if($1$2 ~ /^123456+ABC/ || $1$2 ~ /^123457+DEF/ || $1$2 ~ /^12345699+XYZ/ || $1$2 ~ /^123311+AB23/){print "P," $0;} else if($1$2 ~ /^1234568+GHI/){print "R," $0;} else{ print "U" ","  $0}}' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that truly does not solves my problem here.

Comment: @AbhinandanPrasad, could you describe why and how this is expected to resolve the issue?

Comment: @CharlesDuffyIt's Working for me. It has less if statement then it should work in your case also.

Comment: @user3676305 Can you show the output what you are getting with my command ? and what you are expexting?